# How to calculate lines per order in a cube

Tags: olap, olap-cube

I cant think this one through, any help would be appreciated. I have a measure of the count of number of sales (distinct count of transaction numbers). Now what I'm looking for is the average number of lines per order.

How can I calculate that in Analysis Server 2008 R2?

Comment: I don't know how's your datawarehouse, but, based on your question, I think you need a dimension that represent your orders and a new Measure that represent the lines per order. Then you can create a calculate measure for the average lines per order.

Comment: you need to provide more details about your fact table.  What's the grain?  One record per order?  One record per order line item?